# Optimization for finding all locations of a set of substrings in a string

Tags: python, string, algorithm, optimization, substring

I have a set of substrings in Python and would like to find every occurrence of substrings in a string. E.g.

```py
# inputs
needles = {'love', 'hot', 'dogs'}
haystack = "I love hot dogs; hot dogs are delicious."

# output
indexes = {('love', 2), ('hot', 7), ('dog', 11), ('hot', 17), ('dog', 21)}
```

I'm currently using a brute force method of finding all occurrences of each substring in a string, which is O(knm) time if k, n and m are the length of the longest string, the number of needles and the length of the haystack. I'm wondering if a trie or any other method would make this faster.

Edit: A lot of the needles have more than one word.

Comment: Can you use `re` module?

Comment: what kind of answer do you expect? E.g. the best algorithm would be to use a prefix tree, but it's kind of complicated. In practice you can use simpler approach, something like O(mn)

Comment: I don't get the needles ahead of time so I can't precompile the regex meaning it won't be optimized as just brute for searching @AndrejKesely

Comment: @KevinLu What do you mean "I don't get the needles ahead of time"? How do you get them?

Comment: Basically I make an API call to another service for a set of key terms but they don't provide the indices of the key terms so I manually search for the key terms using the key terms they provided. If I use a regex it would take a while to recompile the regex every time I call the search function. @wim

Comment: `re` still sounds like a good choice to me.  Don't worry about re compile time unless it is measurably a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [special string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns) intended to look for multiple patterns in  text.

Perhaps the most known is **Aho-Corasick** one, and I see a lot of Python imlementations (cannot say what is the best though). [Arbitrary found one](https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/).